# Condition over object's type

Tags: crystal-lang

I need to use a simple if statement based on an object's type/class.

I have a custom Array class and a Matrix class. Elements of the Array class don't have a `number_of_cols` attribute

```
def method(other)
  if self.is_a?(Array)
    c = self.class.zeros(shape[0], shape[1])
  elsif self.is_a?(Matrix)
    c = self.class.zeros(number_of_rows, other.number_of_cols)
  end
end
```

However, when running this, I get an error:

```
undefined method 'number_of_cols' for Array
```

which is exactyle why I have this if statement. 
I also tried `self.responds_to?(:number_of_cols)` in the `elsif` but same error.

I can always make two methods, one per type, but I'd also like to understand why this is not working when there are dedicated helpers like `is_a?` and `responds_to?` to avoid these issues.

Comment: Did you try `self.number_of_rows`?

Comment: Yes, and I get: `undefined method 'number_of_rows' for Array`.
It shouldn't even go there since it's not a Matrix, and the self.is_a?(Matrix) should prevent this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `other.number_of_cols` but you haven't ensured that `other` is a `Matrix`, only that `self` is one.

Comment: Right thanks fixed it, but since I've never called it with self as a Matrix I didn't expect it to run this block since this condition wasn't satisfied.