# Type checking in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

I already asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41311609/condition-over-objects-type) and the answer did fix my issue but I have a more general misunderstanding of how crystal checks types since I keep running into similar issue so if someone could help me figure this out I'd be greatful. I've tried many things that would work great with Ruby but are absolutely not working with Crystal (I know they have many differences but I'm more familiar with Ruby).

Here is a class:

```
class Narray(T)
  getter shape
  getter values

  @shape : Tuple(Int32, Int32) | Nil

  def initialize(values : T)
    @values = values
    @type = T
    @shape = set_shape
  end

  def set_shape
    if (@type == Array(Array(Int32))) || (@type == Array(Array(Float64)))

      return {values.size, values[0].size}      # Line causing the error

    elsif (@type == Array(Int32)) || (@type == Array(Float64))
      return {1, @values.size}
    end
  end

  def is_matrix?
    if @values[0].is_a?(Array(Int32)) || @values[0].is_a?(Array(Float64))
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

To define an array, I should do:

```
arr1 = Narray.new([1,2,3])
```

Which would run through `set_shape` to retrieve the shape of the array (a tuple representing the number of rows and number of columns).
In this method, I check in the if statement if it's a 2D array or not. 
However, when running the line above, I get this error:

```
in script.cr:16: undefined method 'size' for Int32

      return {values.size, values[0].size}
```

Which is exactly what the first if statement should avoid. Since I'm initializing a 1D array, it shouldn't go through the `.size` part.

I'm pretty sure it's a trivial explanation, and that there is something pretty basic that I didn't get but I'd like to get it instead of stumbling upon this issue all the time.

How can I check for type in Crystal since the way I'm using isn't the right way ? 
I've tried using `is_a?`, `== Type`, using the `is_matrix?` method (which works fine and does the job of determining if it's 2D or 1D but still runs through the wrong part).

EDIT: according to the first answer, I've changed the `set_shape` method:

```
  def set_shape
    if (@values.is_a? Array(Array(Int32))) || (@values.is_a? Array(Array(Float64)))
      return {values.size, values[0].size}
    elsif (@values.is_a? Array(Int32)) || (@values.is_a? Array(Float64))
      return {1, @values.size}
    end
  end
```

But I still have the exact same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that you indirectly test for `@values` type, using an instance variable that happens to be the generic `T`. The compiler ain't that smart, and there is a possibility, at runtime, that `@type` changes and no longer reflects `@values` type. Even if you know it won't, Crystal wants to be safe (otherwise the program segfaults). Crystal complains because you assume a type that it won't acknowledge.

Drop `@type`. It's not helping and makes things more complicated than they have to. You already use a generic, now you should ask `@values` for what it is, then act accordingly. Crystal will like that, because you ascertain that type will be this and nothing else.

That being said, maybe you should have 2 different types to denote `Array` vs `Array(Array)`. Maybe your code would be easier to deal with?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried what you advised, which is evaluating @values' type directly but didn't work (see my edit, I've added what I've tried). When you say have 2 different types, do you mean having 2 distincts classes ? Ideally, I'm trying to create a type that would have the same capabilities as numpy ndarrays, which are very convenient. And it seems to me that part of why it's convenient is because it's one type for 1D/2D/Int/Float. But I'm always opened to suggestions and if you have any "design" advices for this class it'd be great

Comment: The problem is that you keep referring to `@values` and don't make a local copy of it beforehand with `values = @values`. The type will be restricted correctly for a local variable, because its type won't change (it's local to the function) but the instance variable may be changed by another thread or another function at any time (it's a shared value), so its type won't be restricted by the `is_a?` call, and kept to be the union.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works:

```
class Narray(T)
  getter shape
  getter values

  @shape : Tuple(Int32, Int32) | Nil

  def initialize(@values : T)
    @shape = set_shape
  end

  def set_shape
    values = @values # => asign to local var
    if values.is_a?(Array(Array(Int32))) || values.is_a?(Array(Array(Float64)))
      return {values.size, values[0].size}
    elsif (T == Array(Int32)) || (T == Array(Float64))
      return {1, values.size}
    end
  end

  def is_matrix?
    if @values[0].is_a?(Array(Int32)) || @values[0].is_a?(Array(Float64))
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end

arr1 = Narray.new([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
pp arr1.set_shape # => {2,2}
pp arr1.is_matrix? # => true
```